# Hystrix: Doing network call in getFallBack()

Tags: promise, future, fallback, netflix, hystrix

I've been playing around with Netflix OSS Hystrix and I am now exploring different configurations and possibilities to include it in my project. Among other things, my application needs to do network calls in `HystrixCommand.getFallBack()` ...

Now, I read that it is best-practice NOT to do network calls there and instead provide some generic answer (see [Hystrix Wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#8-get-the-fallback)) and if it is really necessary to do this, one should use `HystrixCommand` or `HystrixObservableCommand`.

My question is, if  I use `HystrixCommand` should I invoke it e.g., with `HystrixCommand.run()` or `HysrixCommand.queue()` or some other option?

Also, in my logs I've noticed that `getFallBack()` can have different calling threads (e.g., Hystrix-Timer, I guess this depends who interrupted the run method). Here I would like to know how shell calling `HystrixCommand.run()` from the fallback affect my performance, since the calling thread will be alive and blocked until that command finishes?

EDIT: With the fresh eyes on the problem, I am now thinking that the "generic answer" (mentioned above) could be some form of `Promise` i.e., `CompletableFuture<T>` in Java terminology. So returning the promise from the `HystrixCommand.run()` would allow the calling thread (Hystrix internal) to return immediately, thus releasing it. However now I am stuck on implementing this behavior. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a HystrixCommand's execute method. Example:

```
@Override
protected YourReturnType getFallback() {
    return new MyHystrixFallbackCommand().execute();
}
```

If you want to work with async "promises" then you should probably implement a HystrixObservableCommand.